# How scan ANY 2d array with just one function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters, size

I've been looking for how to do this everywhere and I couldn't find anything, I figured that I might be asking the wrong question but here it goes, I've been trying to use just one function to read or print any 2d array that you define on the main and then pass it as single argument on the function... Here's my code:

```
int main() {

    int array2d[2][5] = {{0}};

    load_array(array2d,2);

    return(0);

}

void load_array(int a[][5],int row) {

    int i = 0,j = 0,column;
    column= sizeof(*a) / sizeof(int);

    do {
        j=0;
        while (j < column && scanf("%d",&a[i][j++]) == 1);
    } while (++i < row);

}
```

I've managed to avoid having to pass the numbers of columns by calculating it inside the function, so the question really is what can I do that's not way to complicated to avoid having to pass the numers of rows, 2 in this case, so that I can use this function anytime I want to scan a 2d array I create on other projects?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Are you working with a compiler that supports C99 or C11?  (Basically, is your compiler is MSVC or Turbo-C?  If yes, you've got problems compared to being able to answer no.)

Comment: I think it's C11, how can I check that? :S

Comment: One possibility: show the output from `gcc --version`, though if you're using `gcc` in the first place, it isn't going to be a problem. If you're not aware of using either Microsoft Visual Studio or Turbo-C, the chances are high that you're safe. If you aren't using GCC, identify tha platform and compiler you are using, but you'll likely be OK.

Comment: Yes I'm using code blocks with gnu gcc compiler :)

Comment: As you are using Code::Blocks and GNU GCC, you should be fine.  You might need to specify the command line option `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` (or specify 11 instead of 99), but your compiler is essentially certain to handle C99 (and probably C11 too).  If you have GCC 5.1.0 or later, the default compilation mode is (finally!) `-std=gnu11` (C11 support by default).

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array as a parameter to a function, it "forgets" its size; that is, it's cast from, say `char array[4][4]` to `char *array`, or a pointer to `int`, since an array is "just" a contiguous block of memory.

You can specify the size of the last dimension for ease, but it is otherwise meaningless.

If you wish to make a function take an array of any size, what you can do is pass in both dimensions as parameter:

```
void load_array(int *a, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            scanf("%d, a + i * columns + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, That's what I have been thinking too, it decays to a pointer to array and the number of rows gets lost no matter what, it just that I have used a code where you could get the size of any array with a function, so you would only need to pass the name of the array, and then calculate it's dimentions inside the function...

Comment: No; `int **a` is not the same as `int (*a)[4]`.  You can't use a double pointer with a 2D array.  You'd have to set up the extra set of pointers.

Comment: Oops, you are correct, I put an extra star by mistake. The code seems to work after fixing that. https://ideone.com/OU203e

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to compiler that supports C99 or C11, you should be able to use code like that shown below to handle any 2D array of `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void load_array(int n, int m, int a[n][m]);

int main(void)
{
    int array2d_2_5[2][5] = { { 25 } };
    int array2d_9_4[9][4] = { { 94 } };

    load_array(2, 5, array2d_2_5);
    load_array(9, 4, array2d_9_4);

    return(0);
}

void load_array(int n, int m, int a[n][m])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    column= sizeof(*a) / sizeof(int);

    do
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < m && scanf("%d", &a[i][j++]) == 1)
            ;
    } while (++i < n);
}
```

I'm not exactly keen on the `do … while` loop, but I think it might work.  I'd be tempted to use an alternative definition of `load_array()`, more like this:

```
bool load_array(int n, int m, int a[n][m])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &a[i][j++]) != 1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This would use the `<stdbool.h>` header and other C99 features like declaring variables in the loop control.  I'd change the declaration and call appropriately.  At least this way, you can tell if something went wrong while the data was being loaded, rather than having to cross your fingers and hope.

The question says *use just one function to read or print any 2d array*; handling any 2D array of any type is much, much harder.

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks! This is the alternative I was looking for, I didn't wanted to put numbers on a function's argument, but this is perfect! I can just use the variable that just right behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the total length as the parameter. Please make sure that array2d store in continuously memory (such as the declaration: int array2d[2][5];)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void load_array(int *a,int len) {

    int i = 0,j = 0,column;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        if( 1 != scanf("%d", a+i)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int array2d[2][5] = {{0}};

    load_array((int*)array2d, 2*5);

    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Bludgeoning the compiler with a cast like that indicates a problem.  If you're going to what you suggest, simply pass `&array2d[0][0]` to the function, which doesn't need a cast because `array2d[0][0]` is an `int`, so the address of that is an `int *`.  What you're suggesting works, but it loses the 'shape' information; you can't distinguish between 10x1, 5x2, 2x5 or 1x10 arrays.  Sometimes that won't matter; other times, it will.  For example, if the input function expected the appropriate number of entries for one row of the matrix on a single line of input, it would need to know the shape.

Answer (score -1):

Dont think of it as a 2d array. Its an array of arrays i.e. [[], [], [], []]

So just iterate over each "column" and then find the "height" of that "column" the same way you found the number of columns.

(If the array is not jagged then you can just find the "height" of one "column" i.e. sizeof(a[0])

Comment: but if I remove the 5 from the argument I get a compilation error, so what I do is I change it to (*a) [ ] which it will decay into anyway, but the number of rows gets lost either way, and if I just leave the argument as this (*a) [ ], I get an error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds.

Comment: you should clean up your code first as according to @chux